# cobc generated "Segmentation fault" for gnuCOBOL

Tags: compiler-errors, segmentation-fault, cobol, libc, gnucobol

I'm trying to compile and execute the hello world example in:
https://gnucobol.sourceforge.io/historical/open-cobol/Hello-World-.html

But when I compile with:

```
    $ cobc hello.cob
```

I get a hello.so file. I execute with ./hello.so and get this error.

Segmentation fault.

This program not uses memory.

I'd added the libcob.so to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ldconfig.

When use:

```
    $ cobc -x -free hello.cob
```

It works but without add comments in .cob file.

Also is very rare that cobc generates an .so file and not an .a file.

Comment: I think that question title is quite misleading as it implies "cobc" is segfaulting, maybe "cobc generated"?

Comment: yeah, It could be so, semantic typo in translation, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cobc hello.cob` is identical to `cobc -m hello.cob`, from `cobc --help`:

```
  -x         build an executable program
  -m         build a dynamically loadable module (default)
```

A ".so" file is a shared library, so nothing you commonly want to execute, because most shared libraries don't have a "main" symbol entry point.

... but you've followed some docs, I *guess* those are heavily outdated and may were working that way around 2002 /´(mind the URL "historical/open-cobol"). You likely want to have a look at the manual, if you don't want to execute "info gnucobol" you may want to have a look at its simplest all-in-one-HTML form: https://gnucobol.sourceforge.io/doc/gnucobol.html and in any case you likely want to check out the [GnuCOBOL Programmer's Guide](https://gnucobol.sourceforge.io/HTML/gnucobpg.html)

If you want to execute hello.so use `cobcrun hello` (GnuCOBOL's module loader).

Comments don't work with `cobc -x -free hello.cob` as the file is a fixed-form reference-format (in which line-comments start with `*` in the indicator column = 7) and you told cobc to handle it as free-form reference-format (which has no indicator column at all and where comments start in any position with `*>`).

From `cobc --help`:

```
  -F, -free   use free source format
  -fixed      use fixed source format (default)
```

> Also is very rare that cobc generates an .so file and not an .a file.

Yes, that's rare on GNU/Linux, but you can have it your way: `cobc -x -o hello.a hello.cob`